# How do you add an event from invitations to your non-default calendar?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have two calendars in Google Calendar - my private one, which is primary and my secondary one, which is called "Work" for work-related meetings only.

Every time someone invites me to an event by my email, I receive the invitation in my default (private) calendar. If I accept the invitation it goes to my private calendar and I cannot change it.

Is there a way to select into which calendar the accepted event should be added?

Answer (score -1):

Please check the calender settings and check whether it is not shared as public. Since you have both calenders in same address, work calender should not be public and should be idle for invite accept notification.